# Why is Bret Hart considered as a great wrestler?

Tags: pro-wrestling

Why is [Bret Hart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bret_Hart) considered as a great wrestler?  What did he do to 4 square ring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bret Hart was [the best there was, the best there is, the best there ever will be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bret_%22Hitman%22_Hart_%E2%80%94_The_Best_There_Is,_The_Best_There_Was,_The_Best_There_Ever_Will_Be). That's a part of his character.

As for why he's considered a great wrestler, the wrestling community would agree that he was a key figure in WWF history and a very technically sound wrestler.

A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=is%20bret%20hart%20a%20great%20wrestler&oq=is%20bret%20hart%20a%20great%20wrestler&aqs=chrome..69i57.7105j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) notes:

> Hart is widely regarded as one of the greatest professional wrestlers
> of all time ... He was a
> face of the World Wrestling Federation during the New Generation Era.

[This article](https://www.quora.com/Is-Bret-Hart-the-greatest-wrestler-ever), which notes the question's subjectivity, states the following:

> If you're talking about drawing power then the evidence shows that he
> is not the greatest as his reign as "the man" in WWE was at a time
> when ratings and house show numbers were down.
>
> If you're talking about being the complete package then Bret's more
> reserved promo skills and lack of character usually have big
> characters who could also work such as Ric Flair and Shawn Michaels
> ranked above him. Bret had good promo skills in his own right, I liked
> how he came across as being "real" in his promos, he was methodical in
> his delivery and didn't rely on catchphrases.
>
> If you're talking actual wrestling skills and telling a story in the
> ring and being able to hold the crowds emotions in the palm of his
> hand then Bret may very well be the best. Bret's technical wrestling
> skills were top notch. He had a vast array of devastating suplexes and
> other offensive moves.
>
> Bret was a talented wrestler but also an amazing storyteller. He could
> have the crowd in the palm of his hand.

In short:

- Bret Hart was a key figure during a time in WWF history.
- He was very technically sound and a great storyteller.
- He was not the greatest character relative to other WWF stars.
- He did not have drawing power relative to other WWF starts.